# Create a query cross join many to many tables

Tags: c#, cross-join

There are 2 tables:
A - [Id], [Caption]
B - [Id], [Caption], [AId] - where [AId] - Key to Table A (one to many)
let's say we have the following data in tables:

А:

```
Id | Caption 
----------
1  |  Format 
2  |  Material 
3  | PrintMode
```

В:

```
Id | Caption | Aid 
------------------
1  | A5      | 1 
2  | A4      | 1 
3  | A3      | 1 
4  | Mud     | 2 
5  | Paper   | 2 
6  | Single  | 3 
7  | Double  | 3
```

Suppose that we want to extract the data formats and content and pass the parameter to the function List  of the two entities as a result of the output should look like:

Some Cross Data

```
A5 | Mud 
A5 | Paper 
A4 | Mud 
A4 | Paper 
A3 | Mud 
A3 | Paper
```

It becomes more difficult when we want to extract such data formats, materials and modes. Passed to the function parameter List  of the three entities as a result of the output should look like:

Some Cross Data

```
A5 | Mud   | Single 
A5 | Mud   | Double 
A5 | Paper | Single 
A5 | Paper | Double
```

and so on. Table A course is not limited to 3 recordings on me. Something like that. The resulting sample in addition to the column [Some Cross Data] type string should still contain a column (say [dict] type List ) which will contain a list and 2 Entity B (see. Example 1) and of the 3 entities (see. Example 2) etc.

```
private static List<Data> ProcessData(IReadOnlyList<Property> list)
{ 
    var z3 = list[0].PropertyValues
        .SelectMany(x => list[1].PropertyValues, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .SelectMany(x => list[2].PropertyValues, (z, c) => new { z.a, z.b, c })
        .SelectMany(x => list[3].PropertyValues, (y, d) => new { y.a, y.b, y.c, d });

    return z3.Select(item => new Data 
    { 
        Name = $"{item.a.Name} {item.b.Name} { item.c.Name}\t{item.d.Name}", 
        PropertyValues = new List<PropertyValue>
        {
            item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d
        }
    }).ToList();
}
```

code performs its tasks, but as soon as it is clear that it is only applicable if list.Count == 4 ... We can certainly create a lot of functions and call them, depending on the number of entries in the list - but it's just super spike.

Help create a query ...

Comment: Does it have to be a EF Linq expression or can you use an SQL statement?

Comment: it does not matter